# WooCommerce into plain php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

this might be a very stupid question but I want to know how to do it and if its possible. Is there a way to hook(embed) woo-commerce product page into a plain php site? I know I WooCommerce is a WP plugin but is there a way just taking the product or cart page of WooCommerce and display it in plain php?

Rather than using iframe is there any other way?

Edit: Will be using WP to install the plugin but display the products into a none-WP page just say product.php.

Comment: no way to do that except using wordpress

Comment: Yeah I know, I will be using WP to host the WooCommerce plugin but display it in a plain php rather than WP page.

Comment: Don't know Wordpress, don't know problem domain. Maybe you want to have a own styled wordpress page for it and hiding the link using ModRewrite/UrlRewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `wp-load.php`. Supposing this PHP file is at the root of a WordPress installation:

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-load.php' );
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
<?php
    wp_head();
?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">
            <?php echo do_shortcode( '[recent_products per_page="12" columns="4"]' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've added a simplified version of the theme `header.php` in this example, but `footer.php` is being called by `get_footer();`. Check [WooCommerce shortcodes](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/).

Answer (score 0):

Almost 8 years later... Woocommerce provides REST API that allows one to retrieve any data: products, orders, etc...

to ANY site including non WordPress.

You may want to see general [WoCommerce REST API documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#introduction) and [rest-api for product](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-products), in particular.

The result will be in JSON format, see example of a single product:

```
{
    "id": 799,
    "name": "Ship Your Idea",
    "slug": "ship-your-idea-22",
    "permalink": "https://example.com/product/ship-your-idea-22/",
    "date_created": "2017-03-23T17:03:12",
    "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:12",
    "date_modified": "2017-03-23T17:03:12",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:12",
    "type": "variable",
    "status": "publish",
    "featured": false,
    "catalog_visibility": "visible",
    "description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>\n",
    "short_description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>\n",
    "sku": "",
    "price": "",
    "regular_price": "",
    "sale_price": "",
    "date_on_sale_from": null,
    "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
    "date_on_sale_to": null,
    "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
    "price_html": "",
    "on_sale": false,
    "purchasable": false,
    "total_sales": 0,
    "virtual": false,
    "downloadable": false,
    "downloads": [],
    "download_limit": -1,
    "download_expiry": -1,
    "external_url": "",
    "button_text": "",
    "tax_status": "taxable",
    "tax_class": "",
    "manage_stock": false,
    "stock_quantity": null,
    "stock_status": "instock",
    "backorders": "no",
    "backorders_allowed": false,
    "backordered": false,
    "sold_individually": false,
    "weight": "",
    "dimensions": {
      "length": "",
      "width": "",
      "height": ""
    },
    "shipping_required": true,
    "shipping_taxable": true,
    "shipping_class": "",
    "shipping_class_id": 0,
    "reviews_allowed": true,
    "average_rating": "0.00",
    "rating_count": 0,
    "related_ids": [
      31,
      22,
      369,
      414,
      56
    ],
    "upsell_ids": [],
    "cross_sell_ids": [],
    "parent_id": 0,
    "purchase_note": "",
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Clothing",
        "slug": "clothing"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "T-shirts",
        "slug": "t-shirts"
      }
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "images": [
      {
        "id": 795,
        "date_created": "2017-03-23T14:03:08",
        "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:08",
        "date_modified": "2017-03-23T14:03:08",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:08",
        "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_4_front-11.jpg",
        "name": "",
        "alt": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 796,
        "date_created": "2017-03-23T14:03:09",
        "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:09",
        "date_modified": "2017-03-23T14:03:09",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:09",
        "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_4_back-10.jpg",
        "name": "",
        "alt": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 797,
        "date_created": "2017-03-23T14:03:10",
        "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:10",
        "date_modified": "2017-03-23T14:03:10",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:10",
        "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_3_front-10.jpg",
        "name": "",
        "alt": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 798,
        "date_created": "2017-03-23T14:03:11",
        "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:11",
        "date_modified": "2017-03-23T14:03:11",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T20:03:11",
        "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_3_back-10.jpg",
        "name": "",
        "alt": ""
      }
    ],
    "attributes": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Color",
        "position": 0,
        "visible": false,
        "variation": true,
        "options": [
          "Black",
          "Green"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Size",
        "position": 0,
        "visible": true,
        "variation": true,
        "options": [
          "S",
          "M"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "default_attributes": [],
    "variations": [],
    "grouped_products": [],
    "menu_order": 0,
    "meta_data": [],
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/799"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```